# PHP Programming Website Message

Tags: php

I have setup a really simple php message form on my website but for some reason it is not working, when the designer showed it to me from his website it worked perfect but now hosted in mine doesnt work. I am using godaddy.

This is the code:

```
<?php if (isset($_REQUEST['email'])){
$email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
$message = " Message: ".$_REQUEST['message']." Name : ".$_REQUEST['name']." Phone : ".$_REQUEST['phone'] ;
mail( "myemail@myemail.com", "Customer Service Email", $message, "From: $email" ); echo "<script> alert('Thanks for your message!'); </script>";}?>
```

I put myemail@mymail.com as representation, I know im supposed to put my own email.

Comment: The main problem is that the messages are not being received to the email

Comment: `var_dump()` the result of the `mail()` call to see any errors

Comment: you sure php `mail()` is enabled?

Comment: The mail settings need to be configured in your server's setting with a proper smtp and everything.

Comment: So you guys see all the code correct? I just need to check my server to see if mail() is enabled?

Comment: You could use a third party email client like Mandrill and utilise their API

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.  My experience with the mail function is that it relies on the underlying system's mail feature(s).  Godaddy probably has it blocked. I had this similar problem and ultimately I used a different mail client other than php's native "mail" function.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why you are using REQUEST, maybe because you use both GET and POST with this send mail file from two different sources but here is a quick upgrade of your actual code + a check that will return an error if your php mail() is not set/turned on in php.ini config file.

```
<?php
// First we retrieve our values
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$message = $_REQUEST['message'];
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$phone = $_REQUEST['phone'];


// Here we make sure that the user has filled in the values
if ( empty($email) ){
    echo "<script> alert(\"Please make sure that you filled in your email address!\"); </script>\n";
} elseif ( empty($message) ){
    echo "<script> alert(\"Please make sure that you entered a message!\"); </script>\n";
} elseif ( empty($name) ){
    echo "<script> alert(\"Please make sure that you filled in your name!\"); </script>\n";
} elseif ( empty($phone) ){
    echo "<script> alert(\"Please make sure that you filled in your phone number!\"); </script>\n";
} else {
    // Here you can validate data inside of each strings...

    // Yes he does, Configure email before sending.
    $to = "myemail@mymail.com";
    $title = "Customer Service Email";
    $message = "Message: " . $message . " | Name: " . $name . " | Phone: " . $phone . " | Email: " . $email . "";
    // Mail it!
    $send = mail( $to, $title, $message);
    // Check if it has been sent
    if(!$send){
        echo "<script> alert('Hoho, your server cannot send email by using mail() function..'); </script>\n";
    } else {
        // Show prompt to user!
        echo "<script> alert('Thanks for your message!'); </script>";
    }
}
?>
```